# What kind of math is this in the picture?

Tags: statistics

What kind of math is this in the following picture?

[image]

Four years of college and I still never came across this. Can you even input this on a calculator?

Comment: Looks like the kurtosis or peakedness of a distribution.

Comment: The value of $n$ is not specified, as is the value of $\bar{x}$, which is typically the mean (average) value of a set of samples. So there's got to be some kind of trick there (most likely, a non-mathematical one).

Comment: there was [a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397894/a-wi-fi-password-hidden-in-statistics-expression) about the same image last week, it seems to be kurtosis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that whoever wrote the sign was trying to write the statistical [formula for the sample (excess) **kurtosis**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis#Sample_kurtosis), but mangled it; so, I would guess the intended codeword is probably just "kurtosis".

Comment: +1 I'd guess they wanted to write something complicated looking perhaps as a joke because there wasn't any WiFi.  Or it was on the top of a hill and the word was peak.

Answer (score 1):

It's from statistics. $\bar{x}$ is the mean of a sample. It's a quantity you may construct from a sample.